# How to flag bad code

Tags: c++, hygiene

I want to flag bad code (as advised by the GSL), what would be the best way to do it? For example given the function foo below (not the best example i could fix this easily myself).

```
void foo(std::string& s){
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Three ideas did come to my mind. What are the advantages(disadvantages) of this flags?

1. Comment Only

```
//GSL::Con.2 s is read only,bla bla, ...
void foo(std::string& s){ //...
```

2. Macro + static assert

```
#ifdef GSL_FLAGS  
#define NON_CONST_READ_ONLY_PARAMETER \
    static_assert(false,"GSL::Con.2 is bad because of bla, bla");
#else
#define NON_CONST_READ_ONLY_PARAMETER
#endif

//elsewhere    

NON_CONST_READ_ONLY_PARAMETER
void foo(std::string& s){ //...
```

3. Compiler Warnings

```
#define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma (#x)
#define NON_CONST_READ_ONLY_PARAMETER DO_PRAGMA(message ("GSL:: ..."))
```

Comment: why flag rather than fix?

Comment: IMHO heavy handed code analysis tools are inferior to code review sessions. The first tend to antagonise developers, the second way builds collaboration.

Comment: flag helps the person who made the mistake to learn, flagging do help to find flagged positions for code review seassions.

Comment: what about a code review tool? We use gerrit, but I have also good experience with Atlassian's Crucible.

Comment: Only opinion based: do what your tools or IDE like. Eclipse for example uses `//TODO` comments for code that should be rewritten.

Comment: @MitchWheat: it take less time to identify that some code should be improved than write and test it. And in peer reviewing, you normally do not rewrite the peer code (except for small fixes) but just flag it.

Comment: I agree with @Bathsheba : pull request code reviews upfront (i.e. before commiting to code base) are much better than some heavy handed 'flagged as poor code' down the track